# Script to download website source to a folder

Tags: python, automation, web-scraping, server, web-scripting

I am trying to learn simple automation. I have set up an Ubuntu Server and I want to configure it to download html source from a specific URL and append to a file in a specified folder on the server every 1 minute.

The URL is just basic html with no CSS whatsoever.

I want to use python but admittedly can use any language. What is a good, simple day to do this?

Comment: Would you like to append the contents to the same file or to a new file each time?

Comment: The same file preferably.

Answer (score 0):

Just pip install the requests library.

```
$ pip install requests
```

Then, it's super easy to get the HTML (put this in a file called get_html.py, or whatever name you like):

```
import requests

req = requests.get('http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/')

print(req.text)
```

There are a variety of options for saving the HTML to a directory. For example, you could redirect the output from the above script to a file by calling it like this:

```
 python get_html.py > file.html
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I would recommend using pip3 and python3.

A word of caution- when you name a file make sure that you don't name it something similar to an existing module. A simple typo could cause nasty errors. For ex: naming a file "random.py" or "requests.py". "request.py" works, but be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff's answer works for a one time use.
You could do this to run it repeatedly-

```
import time
import requests

while True:
    with open('filename.extension', 'a') as fp:
        newHtml = requests.get('url').text
        fp.write(newHtml)
    time.sleep(60)
```

You could run this as a background process for as long as you want.

```
$ python3 script_name.py &
```